# Prepare session array key without clearing it out to prevent "Warning: Undefined array key" in php

Tags: php, session, undefined, warnings

I must be doing this wrong.
I'm getting

```
Warning: Undefined array key "notices" in [path-to-file.php] on line 187
```

The code is `L:187  $_SESSION['notices'] = $_SESSION['notices']?:[];`

***PLEASE KEEP READING*** before any conclution at the top of your head.
I have ran into this issue from time to time, and managed to fix them by preparing the varaibles before they're getting used.
Pre-setting them to e.g. `$var = '';` is one way.
Or by doing something like this: `$var??''` has also become a working quickfix for fixing various functions that no longer accepts null values since PHP 8 now treats null as nothing, and not defaults it to `false`,`0` or `''` etc.

**I sort of know why I'm getting this warning**, but I don't know how to fix it in my particular situation.
By just setting `$_SESSION['notices'] = [];` at the top of my code in order to prepare the variable breakes my code...
Warning dissapears, but ovbiously when I do so the `$_SESSION['notices]` gets cleared out before it ever gets used by the actual page after a redirect.

So at first I thought I could just do this:

```
$_SESSION['notices'] = $_SESSION['notices']?:[];
```

Populating the session array key with either the data allready stored, or prepare it with no values at the moment.
The only thing that removes the warning is setting the array key to something:

```
$_SESSION['notices'] = [];  //  or  $_SESSION['notices'] = '';
```

But this breakes my intension of the code...
And here's why:

**About $_SESSION['notices']**
I have a class that stores notices into this session varable to be able to save response notices when redirecting back to, or fowarding, to another page.

Here's an example of a workflow with this:

```
1. User submits a form
2. The action for any form submits is allways " /?script=[name of script] "
3. (Please see "3. Handle form action" down bellow for better understanding).
4. We retrieve the requested script, and we use a class for putting notices into a `$_SESSION['notices']` along the way:
       e.g.  KD::setSuccess('Thanks for your reply');
             KD::setError('OBS! Something went wrong.');
5. Then we redirect the user accordingly to whereever fits the bill
6. Lastly; we display any notices set by the script back to the user
   And those notices is fetched back from $_SESSION['notices']  
   lastly we unsets the notices at the very end of index.php.
```

**3. Handle form action** *(the absolute very first lines of index.php)*
Whenever we follow a link that requires a script to be executed, we get it by looking for `script` or `ajax` in `$_POST` or `$_GET` ($_REQUEST).
If detected, we load a script that handles the request, which in turn then fetches the requested script, and includes it so it can be executed.
From there the requested script redirects the user either back, or forwards the user to a new page - or do whatever we have defined.

```
/** SITE SETUP **/
    require 'setup/__header.php';  //  header includes all configuration files
/**/
/** HANDLE SCRIPT REQUESTS **/
    if(isset($_REQUEST['script'])||isset($_REQUEST['ajax'])){
        include (defined('use_framework')?dir_framework_scripts:dir_scripts).'__script.exe.php';
    }
/**/
```

**4. KD::setNotice();**
Shorthands for this method is `setSuccess`, `setError`, `setWarning`, `setInfo`.
If we are executing a dynamic javascript ajax type of action. Then this class::method will threat it as such.
Otherwise we store the notice in a session named `$_SESSION['notices']`.

```
public static function setNotice($type,$text,$pos='',$rdir='',$chk=''){
    if(defined('is_ajax')){  echo json_encode(['type'=>$type,'msg'=>$text]); exit;  }
    
    /*  code for handling the different paramaters, but for now we only focus on the $_SESSION['notices']-part  */
    
    $_SESSION['notices'][]=array('type'=>$type,'text'=>$text,'pos'=>$pos);  //  add new notice to session
}
```

As you can see we store the notices to `$_SESSION['notices']` variable as I thought that would be the best way of keeping the notice when redirecting to new pages.
Then when after redirect, we retrieve the stored notices with a `getNotices()`-method.

**6. KD::getNotices();**

```
public static function getNotice($pos=''){
    if($_SESSION['notices']){
        foreach($_SESSION['notices'] as $k=>$v){

            /*  we have some code for reading position in order to display only the notice we want at each location. Allows for multiple getNotices on same page, but notices from different actions.  */

            $notices[$pos].= '<div class="notice-'.$v['type'].' closeable" id="notice-'.$pos.'"><p class="icon">'.$v['text'].'</p></div>';
        }
    }
}
```

**Lastly;**
At the very bottom of index.php we clear out any notices that's not suppose to be used anymore:

```
unset($_SESSION['notices']);
```

**Loading sequence**

```
1  index.php
2  __header.php is included immediately
3  session_start(); is set in __header.php, and before anything else are included. 
4  notice-class is included after session is started
5  execution of requested script where setNotice() is used are loaded after classes has been included.
```

If you've read all of this, then you might get that preparing this variable by setting `$_SESSION['notices'] = [];` breakes my code.
Whenever we do a redirect, it will always just clear out it's content before the rest of the page gets loaded since this has to be set before getting used in the first place.

**I do understand** that I've must be doing soemthing wrong. But can't figure out exactly what or how to adjust my code to prevent this warning. And still keep this method working as expected.

For now, in my `__header.php`, I can just do `ini_set('error_reporting',E_ALL^E_WARNING);` alongside all other configurations. Then. Problem "solved" - for now.
But it's not an reliable solution as the documentation states that this warning will throw an fatal error in newer versions of php.
Meaning I will evetually have to figure out a new way of doing this anyways...

Comment: `$_SESSION['notices'] = $_SESSION['notices']??[];` Or even simpler `$_SESSION['notices'] ??= [];`